# How to get Apache to follow symlink instead of downloading it?

Tags: apache

I am just using the standard apache config file which mentions that it follows symlinks, but when I hit the url `http://localhost/test` it downloads the symlink file instead of following it.  What config do I need to change to get apache to follow the symlink instead of downloading it?

This is an ls on the directory:

```
$ ls -al
total 10
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM  SYSTEM  0 Oct 20 10:55 .
drwx------+ 1 SYSTEM  SYSTEM  0 Aug 26 12:27 ..
-rw-r--r--+ 1 me None   47 Oct 20 10:14 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx  1 me None   29 Oct 19 17:10 test -> /home/me/projects/test
```

This is in my apache config file:

```
<Directory "D:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  The symlink I was using was made using cygwin and it crossed drives/volumes.  I found out that's not allowed in windows so I had to move the files to the same drive as apache and the link is now working.